# how can we write data to a file from database function in postgresql?

Tags: java, file, postgresql

i searched many ways but i didn't get the information about how to write the data to a file when call the database function (postgresql) in the java program.. please clarify me on this....

thanks in advance..

Comment: Which kind of database functions?

Comment: You don't need to use Java -- PostgreSQL has command line scripting that can write output to file directly.

Comment: just normal functions used in postgresql.. i am updating a table so i have to  write the updation part to a log file .

Comment: Then why don't you try using java.io.FileWriter

Comment: just i want to update some times only and moreover the program is running in one machine and update the file in machine which is having the database . so i think this is the way.. please provide me the solution to solve this problem or any suggestions...

Comment: You should try FileAppender with log4j. It may let you create file where you want it. http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/FileAppender.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the file to be written on the *database* server, not the application server (where the Java Program is running).

You need to implement a stored function in an **untrusted** language (like python or C). You would then call that function either from Java or from within the already existing function.

Here is an [example that I found](http://dbaspot.com/forums/postgresql/259345-re-create-text-file-postgres-like-oracle-utl_file-package.html) when googling for this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION makefile(text) 
RETURNS text AS 
$$
  o=open("/path/to/file")
  o.write(args[0])
  o.close()
  return "ok"
$$
LANGUAgE plpythonu;
```

Here is another one:

http://www.leidecker.info/pgshell/Having_Fun_With_PostgreSQL.txt

A (very) short description is also given here:
http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2007-01/msg00010.php